# I want to bulk import a CSV file into zendesk using the Zendesk API. Can I use postman or something else to do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, postman, zendesk

I have CSV files with many lines of case documentation that I'd like to import into Zendesk.

I am aware there is a ticket API: https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/ticket_import

Should I use a script in postman? How can I loop through the CSV file to have Zendesk tickets created based on the fields within?

This example here shows how to create 500 tickets based on variables set in the code below. Instead i'd like to loop through the CSV file and have tickets created based on the keys and values within that file.

```
for(x=0; x<500; x++) {
  var title = "Ticket #" + x;
  var subject = "Test ticket #" + x;
  var body = "This is test ticket #" + x;
  $.ajax({
    url: '/api/v2/tickets.json',
    contentType:'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({"ticket": {"subject": subject , "comment": { "body": body }}})
  });
}
```

Comment: What does your cvs file look like?